# Where can I download a standalone install binary for Gedit 3+ for Windows 7 Pro 64 bit?

Tags: windows, gedit

The only install file I've found is on c-net for version 2.30.1-1. I know there is a version 3.2, but I cannot find a standalone install binary for Windows. Wikipedia says this version is available for Windows through MYSYS2, but I do not need a GNU development environment, I just need Gedit. Even so, I installed MYSYS2, which presents me with a command line. Gedit is listed as a MYSYS2 'package' on this page: http://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/wiki/Packages/ ...but I am baffled as to how to install it, and then run it independently of MYSYS2. Could someone take pity on a novice and help me through this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MSYS2 Software Distribution` provides shared libraries and packages instead of standalone installers for various sensible reasons (security and reuse). The `bash` shell is not a `GNU` development environment for if it were, it wouldn't come pre-installed on `Mac OS X`. To install a 64-bit `gedit` from within the `MSYS2 Bash Shell`, enter: `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gedit` then to run it enter `/mingw64/bin/gedit.exe`. You can also click on `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gedit.exe` from `Windows Explorer` if you don't like using the `Bash Shell`. If you installed `MSYS2` somewhere other than `C:/msys64` then adjust accordingly.  We also provide a graphical package manager called `octopi` but it's not really ready for general consumption. Please read our Wiki for some general details: http://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/wiki/MSYS2%20installation/.